# Problem with Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, http, ssl, protocols, tls1.2

My code that aims to return reports in PDFs is generating some errors, initially talking about the SSL and TLS protocols. I haven't found a solution yet, can anyone help me?

PDF generation is linked to crystal.

```
 000000cc SystemErr     R javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:6)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:43)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.b(SSLSocketImpl.java:32)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:626)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:39)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:656)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:533)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:49)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:24)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1207)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:63)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.usiminas.nqppap00.negocio.ElaboracaoPPAPRN.retornarRelatorioComoPDF(ElaboracaoPPAPRN.java:432)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5730)
000000cc SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:568)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.interceptor.OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.callInterceptorsAndDecorators(OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.java:526)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.interceptor.OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.callToOwbInterceptors(OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.java:200)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
 000000cc SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
```

I've already tried disabling the line
#jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768 in java.security but it didn't work.